# Polynomials of roots. Sum and product of roots

Tags: polynomials

If A and B are roots of the equation $px^2 +qx +r=0$ find in terms of $p$,$q$ and $r$

a) $$\frac{1}{A}  +  \frac{1}{B}$$

Hi, im new to this topic. This is not homework. im just curious of how to do this question. thanks!

Comment: $1/a+1/b=(a+b)/ab$ and look at Vieta's formulas too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, note that $$px^2+qx+r=p(x-A)(x-B).\tag{$\star$}$$ Expanding the right hand side of $(\star)$ and equating the coefficients of same-degree terms, we can find $A+B$ and $AB$ in terms of our coefficients. Can you see how this helps us find $$\frac1A+\frac1B$$ in terms of our coefficients?

Comment: Im sorry im unsure how you got he right hand side p(x−A)(x−B)?

Comment: Have you heard of the [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)?

Comment: Ohh yes i have heard of it

Comment: could you please continue with the question. I would like ot see how its done. If its alright with you? Thanks!

Comment: Which part? The expansion, or the last bit?

Comment: the last bit please

Comment: Ah. Well, let me ask you a question. How would you add the fractions $$\frac15+\frac23,$$ for example, without using a calculator?

Comment: common denominator and add so 13/15

Comment: Exactly! When you do that with $$\frac1A+\frac1B,$$ what do you get?

Comment: A+B / AB OOOHHH

Comment: There you go!${}$

Comment: THANKs!!!!! I understand this now

Comment: @CameronBuie I am having a bit of trouble understanding this. When I've expanded the star side of the equation and then equated the coefficients I get that $r=AB$ and that $q=-A+B$. Have I done this right? Its the negative sign that is throwing me off.

Comment: @user66807: You're almost there. You should have a $p$ in both those equations, and that negative sign should be on your $B$ term, as well. It might help you to divide both sides by $p$ before you expand the right side.

Comment: basically A+B= -q/p              And  AB = r/p

Comment: Wow that was a silly mistake, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quadratic formula to get that the roots are
$$
\frac{-q\pm\sqrt{q^2-4pr}}{2p}.
$$

Comment: This is far from optimal. Vieta would work for higher degree polynomials, while  formulas for the roots of them become increasingly complex and then fail to exist.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Never said it was optimal.  Just offered a different take on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $y=\frac 1x$ we have $p\frac 1{y^2}+q\frac 1y +r=0$ which gives $$ry^2+qy+p=0$$

The roots of this equation will be $\frac 1A$ and $\frac 1B$, by design, and the sum and product of the roots can be read off in the usual way (Vieta).

This trick of transforming the variable in the equation occasionally saves a fair amount of calculation.